# Visual Studio Android Emulator Black Screen in Apps periodically

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, hyper-v, visual-studio-emulator

I'm currently beginning app development using Xamarin with Visual studio in a virtual machine (My actual PC doesn't support android Emulation but the server next door does).

Whenever I have the virtual android device (using Visual Studio Emulator for Android) open and am using or debugging apps I get a black screen for some unknown reason, I can stop this behaviour by clicking where the home back and app manager buttons would be and this returns me to the app.

After reading other questions and responses online I don't believe my issue is similar, many have issues with flat out black screens with no interactivity, whereas my issue is different.

### Some specs:

- Virtual Machine I am developing in:

  - Intel xeon E5 2630 v4 2.2Ghz
  - 12 GB dedicated to my machine
- Android device:

  - 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone
  - API Level 19

If anybody knows what could be the cause of this issue and perhaps a solution, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried creating a new emulator?

Comment: Yes I have, and I've uninstalled and reinstalled the emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Visual Studio Android Emulator Feedback to get an answer to my question, I got a reply saying that Microsoft do not officially support nested VM's as there is no dedicated GPU provided to the system. 
However there is a workaround which is disabling OpenGL, I tried this method myself but I find the emulator becomes rather slow and far less responsive. By the way disabling OpenGL is also unsupported.

#### Disabling OpenGL

> In VMWare Fusion, under General settings, for the OS Type, you’ll need to change it from Windows 8.1 to “Hyper-V (unsupported)”. I would also suggest at least 2 processors and 4gb of ram (6gb is better depending on the Android VMs you want to run)
>
> In Windows, you’ll need to edit the c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10240.0\skus\android\xdesku.xml file and remove the following line from the file: GuestDisplayProvider=”VsEmulator.OpenGLGuestDisplay”

[Source of Method](https://creativewebspecialist.co.uk/2015/07/22/how-to-use-visual-studio-android-emulator-on-vmware-fusion/)